# Why my callout only work for the last point it's not working for the others?

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis

I already created callout function for single point it's really easy work without any interruption , but when I have multiple point the callout function work only for last point the others not working I have no idea why I searched in google many times but I didn't get any result, the below Code it's work for single point :

```
  mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {

                callout.hide();

                // Handles the tapping on Graphic

                int[] graphicIDs = graphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 25);
                if (graphicIDs != null && graphicIDs.length > 0) {
                    Graphic gr = graphicsLayer.getGraphic(graphicIDs[0]);

                    Point location = (Point) gr.getGeometry();

                    SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference
                            .create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);
                    Point aux = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(location,
                            mMapView.getSpatialReference(), sp);

                    try {

                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.000000");

                        String latitude = df.format(aux.getX());
                        String longtitude = df.format(aux.getY());

                        Double finallat = (Double) df.parse(latitude);
                        Double finallon = (Double) df.parse(longtitude);

                        Log.e("LLLLL", latitude + ": " + longtitude);

                        updateContent(
                                (String) gr.getAttributeValue("Rating"),
                                (String) gr.getAttributeValue("Title"),
                                (String) gr.getAttributeValue("Category"),
                                finallat, finallon);
                        callout.setOffset(0, -15);
                        callout.show(location, content);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

the above code for onsingleTaplistener , code for updateContent function :

```
public void updateContent(String rating, String title, String cate,
        Double finallat, Double finallon) {
    if (content == null)
        return;

    Log.e("Double", finallat + ":" + finallon);

    Cursor cur = database.showInfo(finallat, finallon);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

        name = cur.getString(0);
        cata = cur.getString(1);
        vic = cur.getString(2);

    }

    Log.e("Name", name + ":" + cata + ":" + vic);

    TextView txt = (TextView) content.findViewById(TITLE_ID);
    txt.setText(name);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) content.findViewById(REVIEW_ID);
    txt1.setText(cata);

    TextView txt2 = (TextView) content.findViewById(CATE_ID);
    txt2.setText(vic);

}
```

and code for createCongent function :

```
public View createContent() {
    // create linear layout for the entire view

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(SingleLocation.this).inflate(
            R.layout.sqmi, null);

    TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.county_name);
    titleView.setId(TITLE_ID);
    titleView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    TextView titleView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vic);
    titleView1.setId(REVIEW_ID);
    titleView1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    TextView titleView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cate);
    titleView2.setId(CATE_ID);
    titleView2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Message.message(getApplicationContext(),"you clicked");

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

it was work for me but when I import the same code when I have multiple point it doesnt work, please I need you comment , thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when you have each Location Pin on individual graphic layers , make sure that all Pins are at the same graphic layer,
**because** if it works for one location , it means , it works , 
then if it works only for the last one , it meast the last one is on the different graphic 
I hope it helps

Comment: sir that's right I have been added each pin for single layer when I put all pins in one layer it's working fine , great answer dude

Answer (score 2):

you are adding a layer above a past layer. try to declare one graphic layer and add all the geometrical forms on it .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show multiple callouts on a map. The callout is always a single instance by design. Besides, showing multiple callouts would be not a good idea on a smartphone, because of the small screen.
What you could do when you have multiple geometry is to show a single callout showing a list of entities, and highlight the related geometries on the map with a different symbol.

Comment: yeah sure you're right I don't need this look bro I have many points on the screen when I click one of them nothing will happen but last one has callout ,the others not