# Why my callout work only for last point on arcgis in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis

I already created callout function for single point it's really easy work without any interruption , but when I have multiple point the callout function work only for last point the others not working I have no idea why I  googled many times but I didn't get any result

Comment: check out this link please ,


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200392/why-my-callout-only-work-for-the-last-point-its-not-working-for-the-others/26403637#26403637

Comment: thanks bro it's so awesome , approved